# Android Studio 2.3 emulator freezes / crashes

Tags: crash, emulation, win64, android-studio-2.3

I updated from studio 2.2 to 2.3 and here the emulator appears showing "Android is starting" and at various numbers of for example 
"Optimizing app 22 of 45." it freezes.

Restarting is not possible as I can not terminate "qemu-system-i386.exe" (access denied).

I already uninstalled the emulator version 26 (version 25 had the same problem) with SDK manager 
(even undeleted ...\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\emulator) and reinstalled it and did a lot of other things
but nothing helps. Any ideas how I can debug the problem (can I set a longer timeout anywhere if that would be the reason) ?

Answer (score 0):

Since, even after re installing SDK is causing you problem. Download 2.3 Freshly again and tell if it's working.

Updates may have created problem, just to be sure do this and post your result.

Comment: I uninstalled and deleted all Android Studios, all directories, the whole SDK and even Java but nothing helps. The emulator (only Software is appearing on screen; Hardware crashes immediately) stocks when building Apps at different states (Optimizing App 45 of 79 for example) and all lasts very long. Is there a timeout I can set which causes the halt ?

Comment: Just to be sure,
What is your System Specs!

Because i have experience working in both AMD & Intel processor, There was always a problem setting up AVD in AMD processor but it worked without any error or hassel in Intel.

Let me do more research in it to help you!

Comment: It's a Pentium Dual Core E6300 @ 2,8GHz (4G RAM) (64 Bit).

Comment: Android Studio is getting heavier then last, and your processor **Pentium Dual Core** can run android studio but it is not recommended. AVD needs more juice and windows on other hand creates more complex in operations

Comment: Check this link [https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-run-Android-Studio-on-a-PC-with-only-2GB-RAM-and-a-Core-2-duo-processor]

Comment: That's a joke!?!?!? Or would it really be necessary to buy a new computer to use android studio!? What a horror with android studio performance (thanks to java :( ) - Then I will have to look for an old eclipse-ADT-Bundle...

Comment: No, need of new computer. And what you said is exactly what is was about to say.. Eclipse is best..

Comment: But, still you can use android studio by disabling every plugin it use, allowing only Emulator to use up memory... Try this

Comment: I did install Eclipse meanwhile but at "Launching HelloWorld 27%" the emulator stocks too. Is'nt there any help how to debug such an emulator problem? Any Ideas ?[See Screenshot](http://fs5.directupload.net/images/170420/ronlma4x.jpg).

Comment: What !!
Even eclipse is boot looping, now i sense some dark magic is around your computer.
Let me dig deeper about your issue

Comment: As I did have a 32bit java on my system years ago even after uninstalling I could get problems between the versions of DLL's deep in the system. I now uninstalled all 64 bit applications and installed 32bit Java and use 32bit eclipse-SDK-4.6.2-win32.zip so that the emulator runs now (even very slow).  -   Now I get other 17 compiling problems ("ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved to a type MainActivity.java" or "Error retrieving parent for item:No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'... AAPT Problem" and so on) but this will be another topic...