# Android emulator keeps on crashing

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

Whenever I open the AVD Manager and launch any one of the virtual devices I created, the emulator starts and closes immediately. When I run the virtual device in AVD Manager for the first time I get an error message that QEMU has stopped working.

I have given the right path to the JDK. More over, I have tried to install Android Studio again and again, but still its not working. I am using Windows 7(32 bit, 2GB RAM, without graphic card).

Is there need of graphic card to run emulator? If not, what should I do the run the emulator?

Comment: I am also experiencing this error. As far as I know from former installations, there were no specific system requirements. So I am currently also searching for a solution on this issue.
I am using Android Studio 2.3.3 on a Windows 10 x64 machine.

Comment: See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43124992/android-studio-2-3-emulator-freezes-crashes.

But my machine is a Windows 10 x64 machine, Intel Core i7-2600K, 3,4GHz, 16GB RAM. So it shouldn't be a hardware issue.

Answer (score 23):

In AVD manager open settings for your virtual device.

In the `Emulated Performance` section open the dropdown for `Graphics`.

Change it from `Automatic` to `Software`.

Hit the `Finish` button to save new setting and try starting the emulator again.

Comment: In my case the dropdown is disabled. What should I do then?

Comment: same problem am having too

Comment: Create new emulator instead of editing @Francesco

Comment: For anyone that has the dropped down disabled, see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58376934)

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution here: https://www.bram.us/2017/05/12/fix-for-the-android-emulator-crashing-during-launch/
It seems to be an incompatibility with other software, such as Docker, Oracle Virtual Box and other products that use VCPU. In my case, it seems that VBox and/or DraftSight caused the issue. I don't get the error when I terminate those applications first.

Answer (score 1):

After trying Vahid's answer, it stopped crashing. Unfortunately it was lagging badly. After **installing the NVIDIA drivers** for my card (I have a 1060), I was able to change the setting to Hardware again, and now it is much smoother.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases the solution provided above by @Vahid would work but if for some reason you still want to use hardware for graphics. You can try upgrading graphics drivers and make sure to set your graphic profile aka **GPU workload** to **Graphics** instead of **compute.** This settings can be found in Nvidia control panel or AMD Radeon software settings, not sure if this would work for integrated graphics.